# .then is run before promise is returned, why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have an async func `getUserData()` which gets user data from Firestore. Within a `.then()` block after the data is received from Firestore, I return the data. This should be the resolved promise right? But the caller of `getUserData()` is running its own `.then()` before my async function returns, so the value is undefined. What's going on here?

Heres my async function:

```
async function getUserData(uid: any) {
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    let myUserData = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    myUserData.get().then((doc: any) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            let documentData = doc.data().tags
            let myUserData: userDataType = {};
            myUserData.tags = Object.keys(documentData).map(key =>
                <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel>{key} : {documentData[key]}</IonLabel>
                </IonItem>
            )
            // setUserData(myUserData);
            console.log("Here 1: ", myUserData);
            return myUserData;
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

And here's its caller:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getUserData(uid).then((p) => console.log("Here 2: ", p))
    }, []);
```

See the `console.log()` statements for "Here 1" and "Here 2". Why is "Here 2" being logged first??? This is causing my data to not display.

```
Here 2:  undefined
Here 1:  {tags: Array(3)}
```

Comment: You miss "return", should be return myUserData.get().then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, change your function to return the inner `promise` (`myUserData.get()`).

```js
let db = firebase.firestore();
    let myUserData = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    // >>>> return the promise here
    return myUserData.get().then((doc: any) => {
```

Comment: So I tried this, it returns in the correct order but "Here 2" is still undefined, whereas "Here 1" displays what I want. If working correctly shouldn't the console.log() statements be equivalent?

Comment: Scratch that. I figtured it out. Thank you! :)

Comment: I see what you mean now, I didn't realize I have to return both the myUserData.get() and again within its .then() block, that makes sense though. I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes when it lets me.